# Chrome.storage.set not saving data

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have an small issue, I am following the documentation from google [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage).
And I am having a issue.

Values are not being saved in storage.
I double checked and the app has the permissions set in manifest.json

```
"permissions": ["storage"],
```

And here is the code part in the content script.

```
// save the new list to the storage
var theValue = 'Some text';
console.log('saving');
chrome.storage.local.set({value: theValue}, function() {
    console.log('Settings saved');
    chrome.storage.local.get('value', function(result) {
        console.log('Value currently is ' + result.value);
    });
});
console.log('saved');
```

"Saving" and "saved" show correctly in the console. Also I activated the debugger and it when it gets to the result variable it says it's not defined, which is not surprise since the call is never made.

Any help? I've been struggling with this for a few hours.

As a side note, I get the same results when using sync instead of local.

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried "chrome.storage.local.get(['value']..." ?

Comment: *it says it's not defined*. Do you get a `ReferenceError` ? Something like `Uncaught ReferenceError: result is not defined` ?

Comment: Since the code in the question is correct I suppose there's something else you're not showing us where the problem actually occurs so I guess the reason is that the storage API is asynchronous and you need to use the result inside the corresponding callback. You can't use it outside of the callback. See [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](//stackoverflow.com/q/23667086)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the messages I made the change to the get call and it didn't work. So I moved the get action outside the set block. And it now works.

This:

```
chrome.storage.local.set({value: theValue}, function() {
    console.log('Settings saved');
    chrome.storage.local.get('value', function(result) {
        console.log('Value currently is ' + result.value);
    });
});
```

Changed to:

```
chrome.storage.local.set({value: theValue}, function() {
    console.log('Settings saved');
});

chrome.storage.local.get(['value'], function(result) {
    console.log('Value currently is ' + result.value);
});
```

And that solved the issue so far.

Thanks for the comments.